# How to remove all fragments except first one?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, android-navigationview, appcompatactivity

My application contains AppBaseActivity having NavigationView with few menu items. By default, I load Home fragment & on clicking each menu item from drawer, I open specific fragment.

My problem is, I need keep Home fragment all the time showing if user clicks back button.

Stepwise explanation :

1. On activity launch, loads Home fragment by default
2. Suppose selects Menu Item 1, loads related fragment[*4]
3. Suppose selects Menu Item 2, loads related fragment[*4]
4. I want to make back stack clear however, keeping Home fragment persistent so that if user presses back button instead of opting menu item from drawer or simply go to any fragment & on killing it, should navigate back to Home fragment.

In my current case, it simply closes/terminates my app.

AppBaseActivity Java (some part of code)

```
    onCreate() {
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.body_container, homeFragment, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(item.getItemId()).setChecked(true);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_terms :
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                TCFragment tcFragment = new TCFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.body_container, tcFragment, getResources().getString(R.string.tc_screen_name));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_about_us :
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.body_container, aboutUsFragment, getResources().getString(R.string.about_us_screen_name));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You are replacing your homeFragment  with nav_terms  and nav_about_us  and hence there will be only one fragment at a time in your container. So pressing back button will exit the app.

Comment: You said you also had an error? Could you post it?

Comment: @ImAtWar Nowhere I mentioned it

Comment: try `ragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.body_container, aboutUsFragment, getResources().getString(R.string.about_us_screen_name)`? it should replace the last transaction. more clearly: it removes and adds the new transaction

Comment: What is the output of this code ?. Also you are not adding anything to stack ,then why is there a fragmentManager.popBackStack ?. FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE is used for cleaning the stack right ?

Comment: @sunilsunny Just mentioned small portion of code, need it for further tasks

Answer (score 0):

try by adding this line with home fragment before commit:

```
fragmentTransaction addTobackStack(null);
```

Comment: try removing this line in all of your navigation  option:-

fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: Can't remove it because I need to clear rest of fragments from stack if user chooses another menu item. Already mentioned in question

Comment: use transaction.replace for menu option then your stack will be empty everytime you click on menu option and also remove  this for every option fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the transaction to the backstack using addToBackStack(). The back press would automatically pop the topmost fragment from the backstack.

Refer to 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

The relevant section is "Performing Fragment Transactions"

Comment: Remove this fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: Can't remove it, there is some specific logic behind it

Comment: Change the logic if needed. Don't get attached to your code.

Comment: i think you will find your answer why i advised you to remove this line see the link below,and serch here for popBackStack function

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String, int)